# What is _attribute_ or things like this in C?

Tags: c, attributes

I often see something like *attribute* in error messages. What is this? Are there any similar things like this *attribute*? Can anyone give me a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [GCC extension](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html) which allows a developer to attach characteristics to function declarations to allow the compiler to perform more error checking.

Detailed Explanation also found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax). A set of GCC extensions for C can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions).